# Why value not submitted?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

```
<form method="post">
        <label>
            <input type="text" value="" size="18" name="searchtxt" class="box"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button" name=""/>
        </label>
    </form>
```

I pressed submit,but `searchtxt` is not submitted,why?

Comment: can u give more code (when u get the form params)

Comment: What are you using to process this form? Some kind of web framework, in some language, presumably. Methods for accessing the form's contents differ between languages and frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're referencing it through the $_POST array:

```
print $_POST["searchtxt"];
```

It's a common mistake to instead try accessing the value as a straight variable: `$searchtxt;` And on a side note, your HTML needs to be reorganized a bit:

```
<form method="post">
  <label>Search:</label><input type="text" name="searchtxt" class="box"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button" name=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: Please note that this only applies if the form is posted to a php script.

Comment: Since the OP accepted this solution, I think it's safe to assume this was for a PHP project. I've appended `php` and `variables` as tags onto the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is a little screwy. The inputs should not go inside the label. See [this document](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp). See if that helps any.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use something like a fieldset instead of a label? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `<input>` elements are not meant to go inside `<label>` elements.